# How to create ArrayList in each index of an array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am trying to implement bucket sort and I want to create an arraylist for each index of an array. I want to do something like this:

```
int bucket[]=new int[max+1];
for(i=0;i<=max/5;i++)
{
    bucket[i]=new ArrayList<Integer>();
}
```

But the above code doesn't work and throws an error. It states "generic array creation".I know that generic array types are not allowed in java but I can't understand where generic types comes here I mean something like  or .I also want to know is there a way to cast Integer to int while creating the ArrayList I hope doing so will fix this.

Comment: You don't need to specify the size of an array list. `ArrayList<Integer>[5]` just `ArrayList<Integer>()`

Comment: @JorgeCampos Yeah I know that but If I use that it says '] expected'

Comment: Candroid had catch the problem... I've missed the types..

Comment: bucket must be of type `ArrayList<Integer>[]`

Comment: @user1613360 i have posted an answer tell me if it is not you are looking for..i will delete it.

Comment: @hoosssein and `ArrayList<Something>[]` is not well supported, because of the way generics are implemented in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **data types do not match**...

You are trying to put an `ArrayList<Integer>` into a `int[]`. It cannot hold this type of data!

please reconsider what you want to have:

```
int[][]
ArrayList<int[]>
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>
ArrayList<Integer>[]  <--- thi is not well-supported due to the way generics work
```

If you want higher performance, you should have a look at GNU Trove, and maybe use

```
ArrayList<TIntList>
```

which should use much less memory than `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>`.

If your data size is fixed, you probably are looking for

```
int[][] bucket = new int[max+1][max/5+1];
```

Comment: I changed it.It doesn't help gives the same error and it's not an answer.

Comment: See the lower part. Your problem is that `int[] bucket` cannot hold `ArrayList<Integer>`, obviously.

Comment: Can you please explain why?

Comment: Because it can hold `int` only. Not `ArrayList`s. It's an array-of-integers, not an array-of-ArrayLists-of-Integers.

Comment: I just wonder why you're using `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>` instead of showing to use `List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();`

Comment: "Your data types do not make match...", I guess there's one "make" too much in there (can't edit it because its too few changed characters) ;)